# Is it ok to name the variables the same name on different methods?

Tags: java, syntax, naming-conventions

i am new to java and i have a question.
lets say i have this code:

```
public class Number {
    private int[][] number;
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public Number(int[][] num) {
        this.row = num.length;
        this.column = num[0].length;
        this.number = new int[row][column];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                number[i][j] = num[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Number(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        number = new int[row][column];
    }

    public Number getNewNumber() {
        Number newNumber = new Number(row, column);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            newNumber.number[i] = number[i];
        }
        return newNumber;
    }

    public int getNewNumberSum() {
        Number newNumber = new Number(row, column);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                newNumber.number[i][j] = number[i][j];
                sum += newNumber.number[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

My question is about the syntax. is it ok to name the object's name the same on a different method and variables names the same on different methods?

Thank you

Comment: Code formatted for better readability. You'll want to be doing this yourself in the future

Comment: When in doubt, try it out! If there's a syntax error your compiler will let you know

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes. Variable names only hold in the scope they're defined in, and you can use the same name in different scopes.

Comment: Yeah i can access them with no problem but my question is: is it wrong to name variables the same?

Comment: @daniel no, it isn't.

Comment: It is allowed, safe and completely correct to name variables the same in different methods.

Comment: got it, i got another question with naming the variable.
i have a different class where i need to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees clockwise..

which name would you give to the new matrix's object after the rotation of 90 degrees clockwise? is the name : "clockwiseMatrix" good or 
the longer name "rotatedMatrixClockwise" is better? i am afraid that those names are too long .. 

Thank you

Comment: see name of a variable does not require to convey info about, what it is going to hold, so you may use any short name ranging from "x" to "matrix2" or any other simple name you can think off and which follows the naming rules of the language, but if your code is meant for teaching purposes, then you may use long names or simply comment the information, just at the time of declaration, stating info about the variable and the content it is going to hold :) i hope it helped

Comment: @daniel please check out the answer, i forgot to include you in my answer

Comment: @PranshuKhandal alright. my project is for school studies so i guess that the professors will want to see a variable names that represent the thing that the variable does.
Thank you anyways:)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are method local variables and you can access them only inside that method, there won't be any issues. So it is ok to have variables with same name in different methods as long as they are method local.